# Restriction of flat morphism to irreducible components of the domain

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a zero dimensional Artin local ring of characteristic zero. Let $f:X \to \mathrm{Spec} A$ be a flat morphism. Suppose that $X$ is not irreducible and each of its irreducible components are of the same dimension which is greater than zero. Is it true that $f$ will it be flat over $\mathrm{Spec}A$ when restricted to any irreducible component of $X$?

Comment: Do you know a case where some restriction is not flat?

Comment: @Elencwajg: No.